# UPS Worldship Integration with .NET

Tags: .net

I have been going through forums/threads. The process that I am in currently is that: I have a table in MSSQL 2008 which has all the info we need to send to UPS for shipping label. Created a program in which it export that table into an .XML file into local machine.

My question is: Do I now need to send all the XML files to the UPS Worlwideship Link? Or one by one? Anybody ever did this before? Thanks!

klm9971

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about integrating directly with a Worldship workstation, but I'd suggest you start by checking out the API and other info on their website.

https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit

And...

http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/resources/techsupport/worldship/integrate.html